# How to substitute template variable using additional context passed to the template

Tags: django

**Django 1.11.2**

I have:

```
<div id="empty_keeper_and_form" style="display:none">
    <p class='no_error'>
        {{ keeper_and_form_set.empty_form.as_p }}
    </p>
</div>

<div id="empty_keeper_or_form" style="display:none">
    <p class='no_error'>
        {{ keeper_or_form_set.empty_form.as_p }}
    </p>
</div>
```

And I'd like to make an inclusion template to use like this:

```
{% include "operation.html" with operation='and'%}
```

And this is what I did:

```
<div id="empty_keeper_{{ operation }}_form" style="display:none">
    <p class='no_error'>
        {{ keeper_and_form_set.empty_form.as_p }}
    </p>
</div>
```

Well, the problem is that I failed to modify that keeper_and_form_set. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have 2 instances like that then why are you trying it the hard way

you can do

```
{% include "operation.html" with operation= keeper_and_form_set.empty_form.as_p %}
```

and in operations template

```
<p class='no_error'>
        {{ operation }}
    </p>
```

Comment: Somethings seems to be clarifying in my head. But what about that id? I need it. Shall l pass "and" and keeper_and_form_set to the inclusion?

Comment: The id for the div: id="empty_keeper_{{ operation }}_form" . This is an empty form for a formset. I have a lot of formsets. So, I just decided to make an inclusion to generalize the code a bit. So, I'll prepare empty forms and later take them and put it into the right place by JavaScript. So, I need the id.

Comment: what if you keep it like what you have? what it displays?

Comment: It displays nothing. So what? Input type=hidden also displays nothing. I prepare an empty form which can be added to the formset.

Comment: you sure about the form is having fields and all

Comment: Yes. I made it visible, then hid it. That empty_form method is described in the documentation.

Comment: i am sorry bro, i have no idea about that. so sorry couldnt help you

Comment: Well, you did help. The question is about templates. Well, the only question left: is it a bad style if I send another variable like I described in the first comment?